# Inner product of fraction of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I wonder if $$\left\langle x\left|AB^{-1}\right |x\right\rangle = \frac{\left<x|A|x\right>}{\left<x|B|x\right>}$$ in general. If not, under what condition are they equal?

Comment: How do you define $\frac{A}{B}$ (assuming $B$ is invertible)?

Comment: $\frac AB$ is not unique: $AB^{-1}$ may not equal $B^{-1}A$.

Comment: @Clement C I would say $AB^{-1}$.

Comment: Then, why not $B^{-1}A$? That seems quite arbitrary for the LHS, and the RHS does not entail such choice to be made...

Comment: @Clement C i would say maybe limited to the case where $AB^{-1} = B^{-1}A$ and wonder if the equality holds in this case.

Comment: So, first restriction: $A,B^{-1}$ commute.

Comment: @Clement C yes....

Comment: You would also need $|x \rangle$ to be a unit vector

Comment: @Omnomnomnom thank you for the answer. But in my case the norm of $\left|x\right>$ need not be one. I see that your answer does not assume this also.

Comment: Multiply $x$ by $r$. The left hand side is multiplied by $r^2$, the right hand side is multiplied by $r^0$. This strongly suggests the formula is unreasonable. It would be better to divide the l.h.s. by $\langle x|x\rangle$.

Answer (score 0):

They are not equal.  They will be equal, however, if $A$ and $B$ commute and $x$ is a unit vector.

Here's a fact you may be interested in: if $B$ is positive semidefinite,
$$
\frac{\left<x|A|x\right>}{\left<x|B|x\right>} = 
\frac{\left<x|A|x\right>}{\left<B^{1/2} x|B^{1/2} x\right>} = 
\frac{\left<B^{-1/2}y|A|B^{-1/2}y\right>}{\left<y|y\right>} = 
\frac{\left<y|B^{-1/2}AB^{-1/2}|y\right>}{\left<y|y\right>}
$$